# Add SSL certificate exception while proxy session via jmeter/burpsuite for an Android/iOS App

Tags: android, ssl, proxy, jmeter, burp

I'm trying to record a session via Jmeter/Burpsuite for and Android or iOS App which interact with an HTTPS API requests e.g. https//api.server.com/login

We can add the exception of SSL if using a Browser, But how can we do so while doing proxy on App for Android/iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is sending the certificate to yourself by email, opening the email on the mobile device and installing the certificate using system dialog.

The certificate file is `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's being generated in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

As an alternative can also consider using [Mobile Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Recorder-Mobile-Recorder-) service, in that case you will be automatically guided through dummy certificate installation process. Moreover, it can export JMeter tests in so-called "SmartJMX" mode - with automatic correlation applied so you won't have to waste your time on developing Regular Expressions to work around dynamic parameters