# Unable to record an Android/iOS app using JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I followed all the steps, after making proxy settings in the device(By adding system IP and Port address) I am unable to access the internet connection in the device(Android).

I am not able to open the app since there is no internet connection.

I opened the browser in device,it throwed me error like "You are offline,There is something wrong with the proxy server or the address is incorrect:ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED".

Comment: which ip and port you are using for proxy?

Comment: Seems like you've not started "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" and if this is not the case then you need to install Jmeter root certificate in your Android Device. 
refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743816/add-ssl-certificate-exception-while-proxy-session-via-jmeter-burpsuite-for-an-an

Answer (score 0):

Please try blaze-meter proxy setting as described in link below.It used to work very accurately.

https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Make sure your Android device is connected to the same network as the machine running JMeter.
2. Prepare JMeter for recording, use the JMeter templates feature, from JMeter:

> File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create

And then

> Expand Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"

3. Configure your mobile device to use JMeter as a proxy, use IP address or hostname of the machine where JMeter is running as proxy host and 8888 as the proxy port.

Please check [this link](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) for referrence.