# Issue with recording a scenario in Jmeter

Tags: ajax, jmeter, load-testing

I have an AJAX application in which I recorded a scenario consisting of 6 clicks using a commercial load testing tool. Now I would like to test the same scenario in JMeter and compare results. The problem I have is that I cannot record it.

First, I tried to record with JMeter proxy recorder. However the application breaks after 3-rd clicks. It looks like JMeter proxy is causing it. Then I tried to record it with Blazemeter Chrome add-in. However it seems that some AJAX requests were not captured, but are necessary to be part of the load test. 
Finally, I used Fiddler to capture the entire scenario, saved  the requests as HAR file, and then used Blazemeter converter to convert the HAR file to JMX. The problem with this approach is that while now I have all requests, some POST request bodies that are in HAR file are not in JMX.

Is there any other way to record or import test scenario into Jmeter without losing request information? Any recommendations what else should I check would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it's just 6 requests for one time comparison, you can use HAR file as a reference, and recreate all 6 HTTP requests manually. Add Cookie Manager on top of that, and most likely you are good to go. If you choose JMeter as your main tool in the future, then of course you'd have to resolve one of the problems - submit a bug to blazemeter people for example

Comment: @Kiril, thanks for the note. While the scenario includes only 6 clicks, Fiddler captured doses of requests because of AJAX. I am afraid that re-creating all of them manually is not only a lot of work but also a source of possible errors.

Comment: Seems like you're stuck with recording https requests, if your application uses https protocol then recording using jmeter requires jmeter root certificate installation in browser/device. refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743816/add-ssl-certificate-exception-while-proxy-session-via-jmeter-burpsuite-for-an-an

Comment: I had a similar problem, perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44716113/cant-navigate-through-asp-net-website-while-jmeter-recorder-is-running/44826944#44826944