# Can't navigate through ASP.NET website while Jmeter recorder is running

Tags: asp.net, jmeter, performance-testing

The title pretty much says it all. When I'm running HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, one particular page becomes unresponsive - when I click on something it just reloads. The recorder itself is working fine, it is recording every step. And the problem is not proxy related. I've successfully recorded other pages of the same website. When I'm not recording, there are no problems.

It's a .NET 3.5 project.
The page itself has a lot of forms, file uploads, etc, but as far as I know, it should not interfere with recording or even more - with browsing the page. When debugging the project, no breakpoints are hit, so I assume that something gets lost before reaching the server.

Browsers that I've tried: tried FF, Chrome, Edge, IE. 
Tried recording the web locally and online. Same thing. 
Played around (reinstalled and whatnot) with certificates, didn't help.

Has anyone encountered such a problem? What could be done to fix this? I'm more interested in finding the solution, than a way around (blazemeter, badboy). Any help would be very appreciated.

EDIT: I tried recording with blazemeter and it worked. But when looking at view results tree I noticed that the request path and parameters don't change, even when in the HTTP Request Sampler they are different. So there's no solution yet

Comment: Try looking at the requests and their response in Network Panel of Browser while recording, you may find a request blocking to record/load with jmeter.

The reason may be HSTS proxy restriction, or any third party application request does not support jmeter recording.

Comment: Can't find any evidence that would support this theory @Yugal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in Test Script Recorder HTTP Sampler Settings choosing Type: Java was all that was needed. I suspect that the issue was related to file upload being involved.

Answer (score 0):

This often happens to me and what I've found is that JMeter changes the root certificate in the bin folder every week. So usually the HTTP traffic is fine but certain HTTPS traffic won't work. So make sure that your browsers are seeing the latest JMeter certificate and not using an old one that doesn't exist anymore. On Windows, Chrome and IE use the certificates in Internet Options, while Firefox needs to have it added to it manually.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but I've mentioned that I've looked into certificates and it didn't help. Tried it again, same thing